Why no $Z$'s in the $\operatorname{F} (\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} 2^j Z_j) \operatorname{F}^\dagger$ operator?
An interesting numerical observation is that an operator defined as $\phi=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} 2^j Z_j$ upon a QFT is rotated into an operator $\pi=\operatorname{F} \phi \operatorname{F}^\dagger$ which does not have any Pauli $Z$'s in its expansion. Is there any simple way to understand this? While $\pi$ is off-diagonal, this is not a sufficient to lack any $Z$'s in its expansion.

As in it doesn’t have any single-qubit $Z$s, no products of only $Z$s, or no factors $Z$ in any Pauli in its expansion?

Don’t have time to work out the math rn, but a potential intuition is that your $\phi$ is a shift-and-scale of the diagonal operator whose diagonal entries in the usual basis ordering are $0,1,2,…,2^n-1$, which is like a generalization of $Z$ to $2^n$ dimensions, while $F$ is like a generalization of Hadamard to $2^n$ dimensions. So the result ought to look like some type of generalization of $X$ to $2^n$ dimensions… again it’s just a potential intuition ;)

No $Z$'s whatsoever.

When you conjugate a phase gradient with Fourier transforms, you get the offset operation $|k\rangle \rightarrow |k+x \pmod{2^n}\rangle$ where $x$ increases as the strength of the gradient increases.
This relationship is a well known property in signal processing (shifts in the time domain become phase gradients in the frequency domain, and vice versa). It's also the key insight behind Draper's QFT adder.
Here's a Quirk circuit showing this off:

